# Gulp not executing the zip task

Tags: gulp

I'm a newcomer to the gulp world, and hence I'm still baby-stepping how to troubleshoot this thing.

The issue: the `zip` task is being skipped, even being defined in the 'default' task.

Where/what am I missing?

**More details**

The `gulp zip` runs fine when specified in the command line (there is no eg; syntax error, and the output is being produced as expected):

```
$ gulp zip
[16:49:41] Using gulpfile ~/Work/........../gulpfile.js
[16:49:41] Starting 'zip'...
[16:49:41] Finished 'zip' after 11 ms
$
```

However, when running `gulp` (without any additional arguments, which means the `default` is chosen):

```
$ gulp
[16:49:34] Using gulpfile ~/Work/........../gulpfile.js
[16:49:34] Starting 'clean'...
[16:49:34] Finished 'clean' after 35 ms
...
...
[16:49:36] Finished 'minify-css' after 750 ms
[16:49:36] Starting 'build'...
[16:49:36] Finished 'build' after 2.1 μs
$
```

The `zip` task is being skipped (!?)

Checking the 'default' task definition:

```
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
  gulp.start('build');
});
```

And the `build' task is defined as:

```
gulp.task('build', ['html', 'images', 'fonts', 'misc', 'i18n', 'swagger', 'minify-js', 'minify-css', 'zip']);
```

Look the `zip` task  listed in the end of the array.
Finally, the `zip` task is defined as:

```
gulp.task('zip', function () {
  var packageName = 'whatever';
  var dateString = now.getFullYear()+('0'+(parseInt(now.getMonth())+1)).substr(-2)+('0'+now.getDate()).substr(-2);
  var timeString = ('0'+now.getHours()).substr(-2)+('0'+now.getMinutes()).substr(-2)+('0'+now.getSeconds()).substr(-2);
  gulp.src('target/dist/**')
    .pipe(zip(packageName+'-'+dateString+'.'+timeString+'.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('target'));
  return;
});
```

Any help [pointing the direction] will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have return statements on all of your tasks?

Comment: @Mark Most of them do have. The tasks sporting a `return` are like this:
    gulp.task('images', function () {
      return gulp.src('webapp/assets/images/**/*')
        .pipe(...)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('webapp/dist/assets/images/'));
    });

I've already tried in th same style, but no success: the `zip` task doesn't run unless explicitly specified.

Comment: Did you try  puting the zip task at the beginning of the build task just to see if it runs there and whatever is last doesn't run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more lesson learned!

Gulp, by default, [runs as much as possible the tasks in **asynchronous** fashion](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulptaskname--deps--fn) - unless you've taken the appropriate measures to force it to run the tasks in a sequential manner.

Having this said, the `zip` task was indeed executed - but it was executed way earlier than I was expecting - hence I was [incorrectly] assuming it didn't ran at all.

Therefore, instead of adding the 'zip' task as one more task that the 'build' task depends on, I made the 'zip' task to depend on the 'build' task, and have the 'default' task run the 'zip' task:

```
gulp.task('zip', function () {
  var packageName = 'whatever';
  var dateString = now.getFullYear()+...
  var timeString = ('0'+now.getHours()).substr(-2)+...
  gulp.src('target/dist/**')
    .pipe(zip(packageName+'-'+dateString+'.'+timeString+'.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('target'));
  return;
});

gulp.task('build', ['html', 'images', 'fonts', 'misc', 'i18n', 'swagger', 'minify-js', 'minify-css']);

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
  //gulp.start('build');
  gulp.start('zip');
});
```

After these changes, the build started to work as expected:

```
$ gulp
[17:04:59] Using gulpfile ~/Work/ij-wksp/smiles-password-form-Q1_2017/gulpfile.js
[17:04:59] Starting 'clean'...
[17:04:59] Finished 'clean' after 45 ms
[17:04:59] Starting 'default'...
[17:04:59] Starting 'wiredep'...
[17:04:59] Starting 'injector:css'...
[17:04:59] Starting 'scripts'...
[17:05:00] Starting 'version'...
[17:05:00] Starting 'consolidate:jade:app'...
[17:05:00] Starting 'consolidate:jade:scripts'...
...
[17:05:01] Finished 'html' after 233 ms
[17:05:01] Starting 'build'...
[17:05:01] Finished 'build' after 3.71 μs
[17:05:01] Starting 'zip'...
[17:05:01] Finished 'zip' after 1.95 ms
$
```